# Wikipedia inconsistency with the index 2 subgroups of the Hyperoctahedral group.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

On the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group, under the subgroups section is stated:

"Viewed as a wreath product, there are two natural maps from the hyperoctahedral group to the cyclic group of order 2: one map coming from "multiply the signs of all the elements" (in the n copies of $\{\pm 1\}) $ $...$ The kernel of the first map is the Coxeter group $D_n$."

It is stated later that the kernal of the determinant map to $\{\pm 1\}$ is a distinct index 2 subgroup.

However on the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix#Signed_permutation_group, under Signed permutation group(isomorphic to Hyperoctahedral group) section, is stated:

"Its index 2 subgroup of matrices with determinant 1 is the Coxeter group $D_{n}$"

Am I missing something or are these statements contradictory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement on the second Wikipedia page, "Its index 2 subgroup of matrices with determinant 1 is the Coxeter group $D_n$" is a mistake. The first Wikipedia page, which states that the kernel of "multiply the signs of all the elements" map is $D_n$ is correct, and there is a natural isomorphism from that kernel to $D_n$.

In theory, both statements could be correct if we interpret the imprecise "is $D_n$" as meaning "is isomorphic to $D_n$".

I did some computer calculations for small $n$ ($n \le 10$) and, interestingly, it appears that the kernel of the determinant map is isomorphic to $D_n$ when $n$ is odd, but not when $n$ is even. I have not thought about why that should be true, but there must be a reason!

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26536559_The_Coxeter_group_Dn 

Theorem 4.1 says "The centre of $D_n$ is trivial if n is odd and $\mathbb{Z_2}$ if n is even.